# Indentation of "public" and "private" visibility modifiers

Tags: c++, class, coding-style, indentation

I usually indent the `public:` and `private:` access specifiers like this:

```
class Foo()
{
    private:

    void Bar1() {}

    public:

    void Bar2() {}
}
```

Xcode doesn't seem to like this, however, so I feel like I'm doing something incorrectly.  What is considered common practice for indenting `private:` and `public:`?

Comment: @BlackBear I wasn't sure what else to call them.

Comment: I think (I'm not a C++ guy) those are properties

Comment: Technically, they're "access specifiers".

Comment: @Mike Alright, I'll change the question to reflect that.

Comment: As an additional reading: [**Stroustrup indentation style**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_Stroustrup)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Religious" question :-)  You will get many different answers I think.

I say:
Which ever you like as long as you are consistent.

Answer (score 16):

Visual Studio does this:

```
class Foo()
{
private:

    void Bar1() {}

public:

    void Bar2() {}
}
```

But I hate it. Many people use it though. If only C++ supported field/method specific visibility modifiers like most languages out there.

I personally like to use this:

```
class Foo()
{
    private:

        void Bar1() {}

    public:

        void Bar2() {}
}
```

VS usually keeps reverting it to its indentation scheme, so I often just submit.

Comment: disadvantage is that, when you have nested classes, you indent way too far :/  How do you indent labels?

Comment: @Foo Bah: People invented those widescreen monitors for a reason :) And I don't use labels.

Comment: +1.Even I hate VS's indentation for public and private

Comment: "If only C++ supported field/method specific visibility modifiers"  I don't understand your complaint:  there is nothing at all keeping you from doing this:  `private: void Bar1() { }`

Comment: Yeah, but VS will still format it without the last indent.

Comment: Is there any way to change VS's indentation for public and private? EDIT: [This is the SO question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876914/c-access-modifier-auto-indentation-in-visual-studio-2010-slowly-driving-me-cra)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to follow a Style Guide, I suggest the [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Class_Format):

> Sections in public, protected and private order, each indented one space.

Comment: But be careful that you only follow the parts of the style guide concerned with code layout, and not those that arbitrarily restrict you to a dysfunctional subset of the language.

Answer (score 7):

Just like *labels*:

```
class Foo()
{
private:

    void Bar1() {}

public:

    void Bar2() {}
}
```

Comment: I agree, simply because indentation and 80-columns lines don't mix well :)

Comment: @Matthieu M: Because 80 column screens are still in common usage!

Comment: @Martin: CLang guidelines have forced 80-columns down my throat ;) I do like being able to compare 2 chunks of code side by side though, so I don't appreciate endless lines, whether 80 or 100 or whatever, this calls for a limit.

Comment: @Martin: I use a 27" iMac :)  I also generally have 5-10 files open at once, and it makes life so much easier when i can keep each window width to 80 chars.